# How to retrieve all Office 365 users in the same domain with C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint, azure, office365

Microsoft provides a PowerShell command [Get-Msoluser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn194133.aspx) to retrieve all office 365 users. I don't want my application tied to PowerShell, so I want to write a C# function to do the work, unfortunately, there's not much information on this topic.

I  looked in the [Office 365 APIs Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605892(v=office.15).aspx) documentation, no such functionality; also I looked into the [SharePoint Client Object Model](http://Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration), no such thing either.

Can this be done without PowerShell? Is there a SDK can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the [Azure AD Graph Client Library](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/azuread-graphapi-library-for-dotnet).  There are also a couple of samples in that link that will show you how to retrieve your user(s).

This library is available as a nuget package. 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/1.0.2

Comment: For this solution, the user must sign up for Windows Azure.